# Bootstrap Popover Reinitialization (To refresh Content)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So i managed to find a way to do what i want, but I'm not sure it's exactly the smartest and most efficient way....

What I'm currently doing is using a popover to show whether or not the user has met the password conditions to set a password. Because there are 5 fields, i decided it would be easier to create it in a hidden html (using the hide class), and then use JQuerys `.html()` to provide the content to the popover.

This worked, until i attempted to refresh the content while it was still open. I looked at several solutions after i couldn't figure it out by myself, and one of them recommended to use the `.popover('destroy');` and then show it again with the new content. However this requires that you reinitialize everything else as well.

There were other solutions, but they appear to require you to use the data- attributes method of initialization, which i couldn't figure out a nice way to do (Because i wanted to create the content in the html while it was hidden.)

Since i couldn't find any working solution, i went with reinitializing everything, so i created a basic JavaScript function, and call `.popover('destroy');`, reassign everything, and the call `.popover('show');`, Then call this function whenever i want to update the popover's content.

I was wondering if this is the most efficient way of updating the content of a bootstrap 3.0 popover, that has been created from JavaScript...?