# Shiny popover from shinyBS displays every second time only

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny, shinybs

The dynamic popover from shinyBS only turns up on every second selection.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("poppy", "Think!", c("A", "B", "C", "D")),
        bsButton("dummy", "dummy")), ## required, dummy
      mainPanel(
        helpText("Note that when you select from the box, popover turns up every second time only!")
)))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   observe({
     poppy = paste("You selected ", input$poppy)
     addPopover(session, "poppy", "Every second time", poppy)
})}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in Bootstrap:

[Bootstrap popover destroy & recreate works only every second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238938/bootstrap-popover-destroy-recreate-works-only-every-second-time)

If you do not want to change the code of ShinyBS, add a js file with the following in your www subfolder:

```
shinyBS.addTooltip = function(id, type, opts) {
  var $id = shinyBS.getTooltipTarget(id);
  var dopts = {html: true};
  opts = $.extend(opts, dopts);

  if(type == "tooltip") {
    $id.tooltip("destroy");
    setTimeout(function() {$id.tooltip(opts);},200);
  } else if(type == "popover") {
    $id.popover("destroy");
    setTimeout(function() {$id.popover(opts);},200);
  }
}
```

and add the following to your ui: (assuming the file is named pop_patch.js)

```
singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src = "pop_patch.js"))),
```

Comment: works a treat. Just have to remember to place the .js file in the www folder.

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I might have found a simpler solution, using removePopover() and Sys.sleep(0.2) before calling addPopover().

```
observeEvent(input$poppy, {
     removePopover(session, "poppy")
     Sys.sleep(0.2)
     poppy = paste("You selected ", input$poppy)
     addPopover(session, "poppy", "Every second time", poppy)
})
```

This works for me without the need of the pop_patch.js file

Comment: I have totally given up using shinyBS because it has not been maintained for 5 years

Comment: I understand. Did you find an alternative ?

Comment: Not fully, but for the tooltips tippy works well. Use the github version, the CRAN version is a bit behind