# shiny addpopover function doesnt work with uioutput

Tags: r, shiny, tooltip, popover

I have created the following shiny App in R

First we import the necessary libraries

```
 library(shiny)
 library(shinyBS)
```

The next step is to create a UI as follows

```
ui =  fluidPage( sidebarLayout( sidebarPanel(sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 
 50,value = 30), selectInput(inputId = "Select1", label = "Select1", choices = c('A', 'B', 'C'), 
 selected = "A"),  selectInput(inputId = "Select2", label = "Select2", choices = c('A1', 'B1', 'C1'), 
 selected = "A1"), bsTooltip("bins", "Read", "right", options = list(container = "body")) ),
 mainPanel(uiOutput("namelist") ) ))
```

We now create the Server as follows

```
 server =function(input, output, session) {

   content<-reactive({
    input$Select2    
   })
    output$namelist<-renderUI({

    textInput(inputId = "text1", label =input$Select1)

   }) 

 addPopover(session, "namelist", "Data", content =content() , trigger = 'click')  }

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The App on running will create a slider and two select boxes and an output that reacts dynamically to user input. the tooltip displays the bubble with read when one hovers over the slider. I am unable to get the addpopover function to work. It should work such that based on the input of select 2, the text rendered in the popover message box should change. The App is crashing . When i place the addpopover command within a reactive environment, I am the renderUI functions output- namely the textbox disappears. I request someone to help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `addPopover` in `observe` or `observeEvent`. I would prefer `observeEvent`, as recommended [here](https://engineering-shiny.org/optim-caveat.html).

`addPopover` will be updated each time `content()` changes, which is what we want since this popover is supposed to show `content()`. However, there is something strange about the behaviour of this popover (clicks are sometimes ineffective) but I guess this is not related to your app in particular.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui =  fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput(
      "bins",
      "Number of bins:",
      min = 1,
      max =
        50,
      value = 30
    ),
    selectInput(
      inputId = "Select1",
      label = "Select1",
      choices = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
      selected = "A"
    ),
    selectInput(
      inputId = "Select2",
      label = "Select2",
      choices = c('A1', 'B1', 'C1'),
      selected = "A1"
    ),
    bsTooltip("bins", "Read", "right", options = list(container = "body"))
  ),
  mainPanel(uiOutput("namelist"))
))

server =function(input, output, session) {

  content<-reactive({
    input$Select2    
  })
  output$namelist<-renderUI({

    textInput(inputId = "text1", label = input$Select1)

  }) 

  observeEvent(content(), {
    addPopover(session, "namelist", "Data", content = content() , trigger = 'click')
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you. So it is necessary to wrap the add popover in an observeevent type reactive environment  to detect changes in the content() object.

Comment: The lack of response is answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491305/shiny-popover-from-shinybs-displays-every-second-time-only