# popup with multiple points features

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

i'm having some troubles with open layer 5
looking/coping this example 
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html?q=marker

having more than one "clickable icon"
if i click and open the popup is ok,
then if i click the map (not icons) the popup goes away, well!
but if i've a popover opened on the first icon, and then i click another one icon, the ballon move up the next, but the content is not changed...

where i'm wrong!? thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_5.3.0_simpleMultipleMarkerExample.html)?

Comment: Or possibly like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_zoomToMarkers.html)?

Comment: @geocodezip There's a problem is with bootstrap popups which can be reproduced by adding a second icon to the OpenLayers example 
http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/icons-error.html
http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/icons-fixed.html

Comment: i've looked here and solved (adding popup-content) https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to destroy the old popup before creating a new one.  But there may be a problem with destroy followed immediately by recreate, see
[Bootstrap popover destroy & recreate works only every second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238938/bootstrap-popover-destroy-recreate-works-only-every-second-time) so you may need a short timeout and the update to the relevant code in the example would look like

```
    if (feature) {
      $(element).popover('destroy');
      setTimeout(function () {
        var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        popup.setPosition(coordinates);
        $(element).popover({
          'placement': 'top',
          'html': true,
          'content': feature.get('name')
        });
        $(element).popover('show');
      }, 200);
    } else {
      $(element).popover('destroy');
    }
```

or you could try a solution based one of the other answers in that question

Comment: thanks, i tried without timeout, and it did not worked (i've not tried with timeout, solved anyway with popup content)

Comment: Yes, if it can be done without bootstrap and bootstrap doesn't work properly then best not use it!